# Conditional bounds on trait impl based on feature flag?

Tags: rust

Suppose I have code like:

```rust
impl<A> Stream for MyStruct<A> 
where
    A: MyTrait
{
    // ...
}
```

But if a certain feature flag is enabled, then A also needs to be `Send + Sync`, so I need `A: MyTrait + Send + Sync` if that feature is enabled. Is there a way to do this without having to duplicate the implementation? It appears I can't use `#[cfg(feature = "...")]` in a where clause.

Answer (score 3):

The [cargo documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html#feature-unification) states:

> [..] features should be *additive*. That is, enabling a feature should not disable functionality.

By adding bounds to an implement block, you are essentially removing functionality, as that implement now works for fewer types.

You should instead find a design that adds functionality when a feature is enabled. For example, you could split your trait in two, where one of them has the additional bounds.

Comment: In this particular case, it's actually two mutually exclusive features, which determines which TLS backend to use. If it uses tokio-native-tls, then I need the Send and Sync bounds, but if if it uses rustls it doesn't. I don't control the trait, and even if I did, I don't think it would be feasible to split it up.

Comment: So it's a different trait depending on the feature (either tokio-native-tls::Stream or rustls::Stream)?

Comment: If you can, and especially if your crate is a library crate, you should make one feature overrule the other, e.g. let `tokio-rusttls` take priority (since it has the easier-to-satisfy trait bound) / ignore `tokio-native-tls` if `tokio-rusttls` is set.

Comment: (Addendum to my previous comment: Of course this only makes sense if no native-tls related types appear in the public interface of your (hypothetical) library crate - i.e. overruling native-tls shouldn't make semver-breaking changes to your crate.) If it does… tough situation.)

Answer (score 2):

As @Emoun points out, this is not such a good idea, but it is possible:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "asdf")]
trait MyTraitConditional: MyTrait {}
#[cfg(feature = "asdf")]
impl<T: MyTrait> MyTraitConditional for T {}
#[cfg(all(not(feature = "asdf"), feature = "bsdf"))]
trait MyTraitConditional: MyTrait + Send {}
#[cfg(all(not(feature = "asdf"), feature = "bsdf"))]
impl<T: MyTrait + Send> MyTraitConditional for T {}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=38fb3a1425a495fbb74e7f4dd1192644) (with `cfg_if` for lowered verbosity)

Alternatively, you can shove the entire `impl` into a `macro_rules` that takes only the trait bound as a parameter, and then invoke the macro differently depending on features. (I've encountered similar [in the wild](https://github.com/ferristseng/rust-ipfs-api/blob/04c2fe96b1e6caac0ce6d52ef648129c3e0b0628/ipfs-api-backend-hyper/src/backend.rs#L64-L65), but I'm not a fan.)